Windows 11 is unable to load Android devices as MTP devices
I have a computer where Windows 11 works fine with my android phone.
However now I reinstalled Windows 11 (all updates installed ) and connected the phone.
The MTB driver loads and unloads and loads and ...
The device never shows up in the explorer and the device manager flips between a new group other devices back and forth.
How can I fix this?
All tutorials I could find want to select the driver in the device manager which is not possible in my case.

Have you tried a different USB cable? You can also check Windows System event log for problems.

Two cables that both worked before.

The event log shows:
Fehler beim Staging von Metadaten. Ergebnis=0x80070490 für Container "{E40D0523-A31A-58DB-BBDB-2DFF7D381450}".

That doesn't seem MTP/driver related - check the log for errors (with the red icon). Anyway you should always mention the event-ID and the event source, both values are not translated in difference to the messages.

@MatthiasPospiech - All diagnostic information needs to be in English
